# Does streaming work on Cloud Functions v2? Can't get this to work

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nuxtjs3

Does Firebase Cloud Functions 2nd gen support streams?

For some reason, using Nuxt's `/api/audio.ts` route works, however, when using a Firebase Cloud Function (v2) instead of Nuxt's route, it will fail.

Here is the Firebase Cloud Function code:

```
import 'dotenv/config'
import { onRequest } from 'firebase-functions/v2/https'

export const generateTextToSpeech = onRequest(
  { cors: true },
  async (request, response) => {
    try {
      const { text } = request.body

      const xiApiKey = process.env.XI_API_KEY

      // Make an external API request
      const apiResponse = await fetch(
        'https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/EXAVITQu4vr4xnSDxMaL/stream?optimize_streaming_latency=3',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            accept: 'audio/mpeg',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'xi-api-key': xiApiKey
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            text: 'hello world',
            // text: text,
            model_id: 'eleven_turbo_v2',
            voice_settings: {
              stability: 0.5,
              similarity_boost: 0.75,
              style: 0,
              use_speaker_boost: false
            }
          })
        }
      )
      response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg')
      response.status(200).send(apiResponse)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error)
      response.status(500).send('An error occurred')
    }
  }
)
```

That does not work.

This DOES work:

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const { text } = await readBody(event)
  const response = await $fetch(
    'https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/EXAVITQu4vr4xnSDxMaL/stream?optimize_streaming_latency=3',
    {
      method: 'POST',
      responseType: 'stream',
      headers: {
        accept: 'audio/mpeg',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'xi-api-key': 'XXXX'
      },
      body: {
        text: 'hello world',
        // text: text,
        model_id: 'eleven_turbo_v2',
        voice_settings: {
          stability: 0.5,
          similarity_boost: 0.75,
          style: 0,
          use_speaker_boost: false
        }
      }
    }
  )
  setResponseHeader(event, 'Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg')
  return response
})
```

Anyone got any ideas why?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"?  Please edit the question to explain what you're observing that doesn't match your expectations.  We need errors, logs, instructions to reproduce, and ideally the line of code that's known to cause a problem.

Comment: The readablestream from the Function would not "stream". However, when using Nuxt's server route , (as shown in code above), it works. and I got the streaming data. Do 2nd gen Cloud functions allow streaming?

Comment: Cloud Functions can't stream an ongoing response to the client, if that's what you mean.  It will buffer the output of the function, then send the entire buffer to the client once all the intended data is collected.  The output buffer is limited to 10MB max and also gated by a timeout.  Neither of these limitations can be removed.  If you need to stream a response to a client, Cloud Functions is not the right product to use.  If you want to use Cloud Functions, you must limit yourself to a response that it can handle.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have the option to use this other endpoint. This one creates an audio file and provides a file, I think, when it's ready.Do you think this would be an option for me with Firebase Functions? https://elevenlabs.io/docs/api-reference/text-to-speech

Comment: I was able to stream in CLoud Functions (2nd gen) using this library! https://sdk.vercel.ai/docs/api-reference/stream-to-response

Comment: OK, your question wasn't actually about Cloud Functions supporting "streaming" at all.  It seems that what you actually wanted to do was just copy the output of the fetch to the HTTP function response, and one way to do that is using the correct nodejs stream APIs (all of which work exactly as you'd expect in CF). The library you linked just makes that easier. All this is not the same as streaming a response of indefinite size to the client, which Cloud Functions still definitely cannot do (and is very much [documented](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas)).

Comment: All of that leads me back to my very first comment asking for clarification of what exactly you're trying to do what does doesn't work the way you expect.  A more detailed explanation would have helped a lot.  It's really not enough just to say "it doesn't work" without also stating what you expect to happen. :(

Answer (score 1):

[`ofetch`](https://github.com/unjs/ofetch/tree/main#ofetch) (Nuxt exposes it as `$fetch`) is different from the native `fetch` API ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), [`node-fetch-native`](https://github.com/unjs/node-fetch-native#node-fetch-native)) and extends the default features.

One of the things that `ofetch` does is allow you to automatically ingest the response using the `responseType` option when calling it. In your code you pass in `responseType: 'stream'` which automatically ingests the response as a stream. This stream is then [automatically handled](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/server#server-endpoints-middleware) by Nuxt for you.

To replicate this behaviour with the native Fetch API, you need to make the same calls that `ofetch` does [under the hood](https://github.com/unjs/ofetch/blob/ff395c2805e27ce137dcaa39b421dcc439f0e22a/src/fetch.ts#L159-L217).

```js
// Make an external API request
const apiResponse = await fetch(endpoint, options) // call as in your question

// todo: handle apiResponse.statusCode / apiResponse.ok
// as you don't want to send errors down to your clients!

// set up headers, these should be copied from apiResponse where possible
response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg');
response.status(200);

// assuming apiResponse.body is not null (as with HTTP 204 responses and others)
apiResponse.body
  .on('error', (err) => { // hook into error event to insert a log message and terminate connection
    console.error("Piped audio stream errored: ", err);
    if (!response.headersSent) {
      // Responding with HTTP 500 where possible. Respond as JSON if needed.
      response.status(500) 
        .setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
        .send('Internal Server Error');
    } else {
      // explicitly terminate connection (signals Cloud Function to shutdown)
      response.end();
    }
  })
  .on('end', () => { // hook into end event to insert a log message
    console.log('Piped audio stream successfully.');
    // explicitly terminate connection (signals Cloud Function to shutdown)
    response.end();
  })
  .pipe(response); // pipe apiResponse to response
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try. I thought I did try to `pipe` the response before, but got server error saying that .pipe() is not a function on the body.

Comment: It appears that I won't be able to use `pipe()` to stream as Firebase Cloud Functions won't allow us to stream.